# If I modify my display name, is it applied retroactively to my old posts, and is it applied to my account on other SE sites?

Tags: support, display-names

I would like to know what will happen if I modify my display name by adding spaces. Will this be retroactive to old activity? What about other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: 1. yes 2. they will remain unaffected

Comment: Unless you copy to the global profile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will this be retroactive to old activity?

Yes. Every place the account is used. We do store the original name in a few places, but one of the few places you are likely to see it in is the `@` comment replies (as animuson [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188278/modifying-display-name/188279?noredirect=1#comment579607_188279)).

> What about other stack exchange sites?

No, unless you decide to make it so everywhere.

Comment: * except cases where you've been @-notified in a comment

Comment: * also except Community Wiki questions where you were the original author (although that may have been changed since the last time I checked)

Comment: How does one "make it so everywhere."

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts.