# What happens when I change display name in the SE profile?

Tags: support, display-names

When I change display name in the profile, it asks if I want to update it on all network sites. That's fine. But what happens to mentions in the comments?

- Does it change @mentions in the old comments? for example if someone says "@matrix..." in comments.
- Does it change the name mentioned without '@' in the old comments. For example if someone says "as matrix said..." in the comments.

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188279/148878) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59885/148878) answers but that was three years back (july 2010). Has the things changed now as they provide auto-suggest for @mentions.

Comment: @gparyani, I have seen this question (and mentioned clearly in my question). Please read the last two sentences of my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content of any existing comments is not modified in any way. The automatic suggestion mechanism will update to recognize your new display name the next time someone wants to reply to you, but previous comments will continue to refer to you the way they did at the time they were posted, whether or not the @ syntax was used.

Comment: hmmm... got it. But that's sad. I can verify your answer as I dig through the responses on all network sites (where I am active) and found references of my old name on comments.

Comment: References *to* you in comments (like @-pings) don't update, but comments you posted will now be signed with your new name.  (I just did this on one site and this is what I see.)

Comment: @Monica Cellio: Indeed, only the *content* of comments is not modified. I'll clarify that.

Comment: True, the `@username` in comments is raw text and doesn't get any "special treatment".